# Object not found error in R function during importing from excel

Tags: r, object, dplyr, error-handling, split

```
LCI.materials <- read.csv('LCImaterials.csv')

LCA.bridge <- function(length, width, height, thickness, girder.Option, deck.Option, materials) {
 
  prefab.girder.Section <- 0.78
  steel.girders.unitWeight <- 317 #the weight for HEM800 steel profile
  asphalt.Q <- length * width * thickness
  
  materials.split <- split(materials, materials$scope)
  
  # calculate the volume of the deck based on different materials strategies
  if(deck.Option == "RC") {
    deck.volume <- length * width * height
    interventions.deck <- 2.5
  } else if (deck.Option == "PRC") {
    deck.volume <- 0.5 * length * width * height
    interventions.deck <- 2
  } else if (deck.Option == "FRP") {
    deck.volume <- 0.2 * length * width * height
    interventions.deck <- 1
  }
  
  #girder options
  if (girder.Option == "PRC") {
    #get the numbers of girders
    n <-round(width / 3.75, 0)
    interventions.girders <- 2
    #get the volume of the concrete for the prefab girders
    girders.V <- n * prefab.girder.Section * length
  } else if (girder.Option == "steel") {
    n <- round(width / 3, 0)
    girders.V <- n * steel.girders.unitWeight * length
    interventions.girders <- 2
  } else if (girder.Option == "none") {
    n <- 0
    girders.V <- 0
    interventions.girders <- 0
  }
  
asphalt <- mutate(materials.split$asphalt, bridge.Q = asphalt.Q, interventions = 12)
deck <- mutate(materials.split[[deck.Option]], bridge.Q = deck.volume, interventions = interventions.deck)

if (!is.null(materials.split[[girder.Option]])) {
  girders <- mutate(materials.split[[girder.Option]], bridge.Q = girders.V, interventions = interventions.girders)
  LCA.matrix <- rbind(deck, girders, asphalt)
} else {
  LCA.matrix <- rbind(deck, asphalt)
}

LCA.matrix <- mutate(LCA.matrix, TotalMaterials.Q = **strong text**quantities * bridge.Q / 1000,
                     materials.LC = TotalMaterials.Q * interventions,
                     Energy.LC = materials.LC * energy,
                     CO2.LC = materials.LC * CO2 * 1000,
                     NOx.LC = materials.LC * NOx * 1000,
                     SO2.LC = materials.LC * SO2 * 1000)

LCA.results <- list(Energy = sum(LCA.matrix$Energy.LC),
                    CO2 = sum(LCA.matrix$CO2.LC),
                    NOx = sum(LCA.matrix$NOx.LC),
                    SO2 = sum(LCA.matrix$SO2.LC))

return(LCA.results)

}

b.length <- 16 # units: m
b.width <- 15 #units m
bd.depth <- 0.25 #units m
asphalt.tk <- 0.12 #units m

girder.Options <- c("PRC", "steel", "none")
deck.options <- c("RC", "PRC", "FRP")

Option1 <- LCA.bridge(b.length, b.width, bd.depth, asphalt.tk, girder.Options[1], deck.options[1], LCI.materials)
```

Hello people. This R function is completely working without any problem. It is reading a small table from excel. I am asking this. How can this function understand and read the quantities column well? I made it bold. I am doing a similar thing to this function but I am always getting an error:

Error in LCA.bridge(b.length, b.width, b.height, b.thickness, column.Options[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUfKw.png),  :
'quantities' can not be found

Here is my small table.
[image]

I want to understand how the first code can recognize/understand/find the "quantities" from small table? How can we read a column from a CSV file in R by using dplyr and mutate? Could you please explain to me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `*.csv` is a text file where lines represent rows with an equal number of cells delimited by (usually) commas. It's not an Excel file. It's a common standard for data sharing, so modern statistical tools all have built-in mechanisms to parse such files. `read.csv` is one of the parses in R. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) for further reading.

Comment: `df = rio::import(filename.csv)` should do the trick. Then you can mutate using `df = df %>% mutate(newcolumn = variable_1 + variable_2)` or something like that. But what you have there...is stored a little differently to how R might normally expect things

Comment: Should I put both of them into LCI.bridge function or outside? 'df = rio::import(LCImaterials.csv' and is my new column quantities? and what will be my variables? I only have problem with the connection of some excel columns and calculations in R. I could not connect them properly. I think.

Answer (score 1):

```
  LCA.matrix <- c(LCA.matrix | 
    mutate(TotalMaterials.Q = quantities * bridge.Q / 1000) |
    mutate(materials.LC = TotalMaterials.Q * interventions) |
    mutate(Energy.LC = materials.LC*energy) |
    mutate(CO2.LC = materials.LC*CO2*1000) |
    mutate(NOx.LC = materials.LC*NOx*1000) |
    mutate(SO2.LC = materials.LC*SO2*1000))
```

Thanks for the idea, I deleted the previous one and tried to add this.But still bridge.Q can not be found. I could not understand the problem.

Comment: Because bridge.Q is a column in LCA.matrix. With `CA.matrix <- c(LCA.matrix` you are creating a list of objects, not new columns in the CA.matrix itself.

Comment: Hi again. What should I do? How can eliminate this error? I still could not solve the problem. There is a tutorial about this. I am doing very similar things and I ran that code and there is no error but I am getting this error in my example.

Answer (score 0):

The first line of your code reads the .csv file and transfer it to data.frame object named LCI.materials:

```
LCI.materials <- read.csv('LCImaterials.csv')
```

For testing ppurposes I have created such file with 2 lines and loaded it. If we would like to see what's inside, `head()` function helps:

```
head(LCI.materials)
  material scope quantities energy   CO2   NOx   SO2
1    Brick brick          1   3.56 0.271 0.050 0.100
2   Cement    RC        167   3.26 0.822 0.177 0.065
```

As you see, the columns corresponds to these, you have in `.csv` file, including `quantities`.

The last parameter of `LCA.bridge` function is named `materials`, and when you call this function in the last line of your code:

```
Option1 <- LCA.bridge(b.length, b.width, bd.depth, asphalt.tk, girder.Options[1], deck.options[1], LCI.materials)
```

you substitute `materials` with the `LCI.materials` data frame. Internally, the functions splits the `LCI.materials` by the `scope`:

```
    materials.split <- split(materials, materials$scope)
```

There is another observation: your `LCA.bridge` function looks for `asphalt` in the materials data frame:

```
asphalt <- 
      mutate(materials.split$asphalt,
             bridge.Q = asphalt.Q,
             interventions = 12)
```

However in your example (in small table) there is no such material. Might that be an issue?

Grzegorz

Comment: it was useful but there is another problem with mutate.

Answer (score 0):

> it was useful but there is another problem with mutate

Not sure what you would like to achieve in this part:

```
LCA.matrix <- c(LCA.matrix, TotalMaterials.Q = quantities * bridge.Q / 1000,
                       materials.LC = TotalMaterials.Q * interventions,
                       Energy.LC = materials.LC * energy,
                       CO2.LC = materials.LC * CO2 * 1000,
                       NOx.LC = materials.LC * NOx * 1000,
                       SO2.LC = materials.LC * SO2 * 1000)
```

If the intention is to calculate additional columns like  TotalMaterials.Q etc, then use mutate:

```
LCA.matrix <- LCA.matrix |> 
  mutate(TotalMaterials.Q = quantities * bridge.Q / 1000) |>
  mutate(materials.LC = TotalMaterials.Q * interventions)
  [...]
```

Regards,
Grzegorz

Comment: Actually, in this example there are two possiblities from two sides. And we are trying to match them one by one and trying to crate a matrix. For example; 1. brick abutment with concrete column, 2. brick abutment with steel column, 3. concrete abutment with concrete column, 4. concrete abutment with steel column. This is the matrix that I wanted to crate with emission values.

Comment: the problem here is R can not find bridge.Q which I put this into mutate functions earlier. It can be seen from my previous answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
  LCA.matrix <- LCA.matrix |> 
    mutate(TotalMaterials.Q = quantities * bridge.Q / 1000) |>
    mutate(materials.LC = TotalMaterials.Q * interventions) |>
    mutate(Energy.LC = energy ) |>
    mutate(CO2.LC = CO2 * 1000) |>
    mutate(NOx.LC = NOx*1000) |>
    mutate(SO2.LC = SO2*1000)
```

should do the trick

Comment: I tried this but still bridge.Q can not be found. I could not connect this csv file with R properly.

Comment: But it seems, there shall be no influence of the csv file on bridge.Q, as bridge.Q is just: bridge.Q = column.volume and column.volume is calculated as: column.volume <- length * width * height, and all 3 values are supplied with the function.